# Call to a member function addUnauthenticatedActions() on null (CakePHP Authentication)

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to implement the CMS Tutorial - Authentication for CakePHP and I am only trying to implement the login page up till now but it is giving me an error on this line

```
$this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['login']);
```

Error:
Call to a member function addUnauthenticatedActions() on null

UsersController:

```
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event){
parent::beforeFilter($event);
// Configure the login action to not require authentication, preventing
// the infinite redirect loop issue
$this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['login']);
}

public function initialize() :void{
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');
}
```

Comment: You are either calling this somewhere you're not supposed to (it needs to be in a controller), or else you're not loading the Authentication component.

Comment: I updated the code with the UsersController code

Comment: There should be a call to `parent::initialize()` in your initialize function? May or may not make a difference. If you `debug(get_class($this->Authentication))` right after you load that component, does it have the expected class?

Comment: I added the parent::initialize() and is giving me a 404 error The requested URL was not found on this server.
It should redirect me to the login page not an error 4040 right?

I then added the debug(get_class($this->Authentication)) and is telling the following : APP/Controller\UsersController.php (line 13)
'Authentication\Controller\Component\AuthenticationComponent'

Comment: That looks like the right class, but the 404 error is certainly a concern. Makes me think that maybe your issue is somewhere else entirely, and this is all just a symptom of that other issue.

Comment: I'm going to try to follow a guide on youtube rather than the cookbook's tutorial maybe that will work

Comment: Should the initialize inside the Users Controller get the initialized components from the app controller rather than initialize them inside the initialize() methods of the user's controller? Shouldn't I be able to debug the authentication class through the users controller without initializing it inside the users controller?

Comment: If you need those components in other controllers, then you should initialize them in your AppController, and the call to `parent::initialize()` will set them up for you. If you only ever need them in the UsersController, then it's fine to initialize them there, though your AppController might well still have other initialization that it needs to do, so the parent call is still important.

Answer (score 0):

in your appController use `$this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['someactions']);`

and if you want to use UnauthenticatedActions in your controller you nit to put

```
public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
{
  parent::beforeFilter($event);
  $this->Authentication->allowUnauthenticated(['actions']);
}
```